# How to handled event? wpf to console

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, event-handling, console-application

I have created a WPF app that communicates with the controller with dll. The first button starts the communication and the second button opens the relay - it works.

```
delegate void RecvData(ref int iReturn, ref int iLockStatus, ref int iUsedStatus);
private RecvData RecvEvent;

[DllImport("KRComm.dll")]
static extern int OpenComm(int ACommType, int ACommPort, StringBuilder TCPAdr);
[DllImport("KRComm.dll")]
static extern int OpenLock(Int16 ALockAddr, RecvData recvdata);
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    RecvEvent = new RecvData(RecvStatus);
}
```

WPF using click button handler

```
((System.Windows.Controls.Button)(target)).Click += new System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler(this.Button_Click);
```

I created a console application where starting communication works for me, but it does not open the relay.

My opinion is that i don't have a simulated handler.
Can you help me ?